# How to set color on hover and disable for '<a>' tag using theme palette in angularjs material, Not with CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

For '`<a>`' tag I'm setting hover colour and disable colour using CSS. But I need to set hover and disable colour using a colour theme palette. Not with CSS.

```
Here is my code link https://codepen.io/vjmadamala7/pen/qQLNjO
```

Help welcome, Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by color them palette? do you want hex code for colors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Material design - md-colors on button hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632591/angularjs-material-design-md-colors-on-button-hover)

Comment: unfortunately, as the documentation and this possible duplicate both suggest, material theme colors on hover are not directly supported.

Comment: In fact, changing colors on hover is actively discouraged in the Material Design Specification.  https://material.io/design/color/#color-theme-creation

Comment: Not hex color, @NarendraMongiya without define color in css file. I need to set by using Theme color palettes for hover and disable state for '<a>' tag.

Comment: @Claies is not possible to set a color hover and disable state